# Simple guess the number game app on android studio. When running the apk in my physical device it force closes instantly

Tags: java, android-studio, apk

i am making a simple guess the number game. i want it to generate a random number at start. then when i enter a number and confirm it will check whether it matches with the random number generated. you have 5 chances and when you get it wrong it deducts a try from 5. when i press retry i want the random number and the try count to reset.
the XML file is given below
[This is the app layout][1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:text="@string/the_guessing_game"
        android:textColor="#519169"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="372dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/are_you_ready_guess_a_number_between_1_20_and_confirm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.259"
        android:onClick="onConfirmClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/retry"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976"
        android:onClick="onRetryClick"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my main java file

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.nextInt(20);
    int tries = 5;

    TextView result = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    EditText confirm = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onConfirmClick (View view){
        int pass = Integer.parseInt(confirm.getText().toString());
        if (tries >= 0) {
            confirm.setText("Sorry your chances are over. Please retry");
        } else {
            if (pass != number) {
                tries = tries - 1;
                confirm.setText("That's kinda wrong. chances remaining: " + tries);

            } else if (pass == number) {
                confirm.setText("NICE. your answer is correct!. press retry to play again.");

            } else {
                confirm.setText("Don't you understand what a number is?");
            }

        }

        }

    public void onRetryClick (View view){
        number = random.nextInt(20);
        tries = 5;
        }
    }
```

I cant seem to find what the problem is. everything seems fine but the apk force closes. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Edit: i checked all the ide given errors. I corrected those. Still its not running

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K6ZE.png
```

Comment: check the console.you can find errors and code lines which cause the crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The findViewById should come inside onCreate please try using it this way! If still you are getting crash Go to Run tab which will be present below and share to error from there.
If this resolution helped you please mark as correct.
Thank You..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(20);
int tries = 5;

TextView result;
EditText confirm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
result = findViewById(R.id.textView);
confirm = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
}

public void onConfirmClick (View view){
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(confirm.getText().toString());
    if (tries >= 0) {
        confirm.setText("Sorry your chances are over. Please retry");
    } else {
        if (pass != number) {
            tries = tries - 1;
            confirm.setText("That's kinda wrong. chances remaining: " + tries);

        } else if (pass == number) {
            confirm.setText("NICE. your answer is correct!. press retry to play again.");

        } else {
            confirm.setText("Don't you understand what a number is?");
        }

    }

    }

public void onRetryClick (View view){
    number = random.nextInt(20);
    tries = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. that fixed it and its running. I didnt know i had to define the variables before hand but get the data from the input in another class. thank you so much!